# I need to get values of Password field using Jquery .each function?

Tags: jquery

I have used below code
jQuery("#change").submit(function() {

```
  jQuery.each(jQuery('input[type=password]'),function(index,value){
```

//I need get values of password input field values for validation purpose

```
});
return false;
```

});

I also have used three password input fields in my form

Please any one help me how to get values inside the jquery each function?

Answer (score 3):

```
$('input[type=password]').each(function(){
    alert($(this).val());
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$('input[type=password]').each(function(i,item){ alert( $(item).val() ) })
```

Answer (score 1):

Just modify your code like below

```
            $('input[type=password]').each(function(index,value)
            {
                // Here value(parameter) is an object
                alert(value.value);
            });
```